# ContentObserver for listening contact changes

Tags: android, android-contacts, contentobserver, android-query

I really don't understand why content observer listens the changes which is not related with the contact info.

I simply registered to the URI which I wanna listen the changes:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, true, contactsObserver);
```

But after calling someone or texting to someone, it triggers and calls onChange method in ContentObserver. So I need to re-sync all the contact list with my application although I don't need to do.

Only field I am interested in:

- ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
- ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
- ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER

What kind of changes should I implement to listen the changes for this DB items?

Comment: got any solution to it,if yes please guide me..i am having the same problem since last 1 week

Comment: @user3475052 a recent answer may interest you.

Comment: Still facing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Contacts database has a field `ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED`
This field is updated every time you contact someone in your contact list.

It is even possible to update this field using your own app, which means, if you contact any contact using an app that updates this field, your `onChange()` method will be called.

Comment: There are more fields like this one, `ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` for example.

Comment: this is a very old question, not sure if OP is still waiting, but maybe @user3475052 will be interested ?